# Search based on list item class

Tags: php, class, search, html-lists

I'm not too familiar with anything beyond writing markup and CSS, and I have a question..

If I have one .html page with a structure like this:

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Now let's assume each of these list items has a class assigned to it, but the class is not unique, and is used multiple times. Is it possible to fetch all list items based on a certain class to another .html page? For example, summon all list items with class "red" to a page called red.html, and all items with class "blue" to blue.html.

Is there any simple way to do this with PHP or another basic method?

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

lets say that is your html:

```
<ul id="list">
<li class="red"></li>
<li class="blue"></li>
<li class="red"></li>
```

then you could accomplish this with javascript by grabbing the desired elements and then sending these using ajax method to desired page.

```
$(function(){

var elements = $('#list').children('.red');

$('#button').click(function(){  
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'somepage.php',
        data: elements,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
      }
    });   
});
```

});

Note that i'm using jQuery here, it would look differently in plain javascript... hope this helps :)

Comment: I am using jQuery included on each page, and have some jQuery in use, but could I ask the meaning of each part of this script?

The first part, is that the parent ID and the list item class I wish to fetch?

In the function written out, which part defines the original page the content is sourcing from, and what defines the page it's being sent to. Is "url:" the source of the content, or the destination?

Thank you very much for responding, by the way.

Comment: `elements` is an array of all the childred of `list` that have the `red` class. The next part says that when you click on the element with ID `button`, it should perform an AJAX call to the script `somepage.php`, with the array as the parameters (but he hasn't given the parameter a name, so I'm not sure how it will appear in `$_POST` in the script). It's expected to format the data in HTML, and that HTML will then be inserted into the element on the page with class `result` (it seems like it would be more appropriate to use an ID here, since you probably only want to insert it in one place).