# How to fetch list items by class from one page to another?

Tags: php, class, search, html-lists

This is a continuation of a previous question, and I tried the previous method and I'm unsure if I did it correctly, or if it performs the intended function. I'm hoping there's a way to do this with PHP.

[Search based on list item class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548151/search-based-on-list-item-class)

I'll provide a more detailed explanation this time so I can better understand the logic of the code, and what I'm trying to do.

For example:

domain.com/default.html (the page all of the items I want to retrieve are on)

Below are the pages I want to export these list items to:

```
domain.com/section/red.html
domain.com/section/blue.html
domain.com/section/green.html
```

On the source page, I want to label list items in an unordered list with classes red, blue, or green, and send them(with all of their markup within the li tag) in the same order they appear on the source page, to their respective pages mentioned above. All list items with class red will be sent to red.html, class blue to blue.html, etc.

```
<div id="list">
<ul>
<li class="red"></li> (to red.html)
<li class="green"></li> (to green.html)
<li class="red"></li> (to red.html)
<li class="blue"></li> (to blue.html)
<li class="red"></li> (to red.html)
<li class="green"></li> (to green.html)
</ul>
</div>
```

Also, how would I specify on the destination pages where the exported markup from the source page would be placed?

Is there any simple way to do this with PHP?

Any input or assistance is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are your list items hyperlink to the corresponding page?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. But no, there are no hyperlinks in the list items.

Comment: for a ex: <li class="red"><a href="red.htm">ITEM 1</a></li> Do you need this kind of thing? oterwise explain little bit further. I can't understand your question.

Comment: I'm trying to have the content from the default.html page duplicated on external pages based on the list item's class. Like all items with red as the class will be sent to red.html, and all the items with blue will be sent to blue.html

Comment: OK, you need load red.html from default.html by filtering class="red" elements. am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this example. I think this will be help for you.

```
​$("#submit").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($("ul").find(".red").text());
});​
```

I have load all the data related to a particular class when submit the form which I added. You can load them when you load the page.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mangalauwu/guevz/)

Comment: I just tried the fiddle and in theory, yes, that is what I want. But I need it to export the content from default.html by class to their respective pages. Like in the fiddle with the red class, this would be on /default.html, and I'd like it sent to /section/red.html, and the same for all other classes/pages. Could you explain how I could set the destination, and how to get it to parse on the destination page?

Comment: you can load related data in the $(document).ready(); of those html pages. (red.htm, green.htm)

Comment: I'm not that familiar with jQuery. I apologize if I'm asking too much, but I don't quite understand still.
Let's consider the destination pages in the /section/ folder(red.html, blue.html, green.html). Consider the classes I want to retrieve are in the root default.html page. Let's take class red on default.html, and sending it to /section/red.html for example now. Do I have to place any code on the default.html page for this action, or is it just on red.html? And can you write out exactly what I'd have to place on red.html considering the information provided? Sorry, I'm new to scripting.